# Beginner Solidity developer here, I want to deploy my first contract to a testnet. Should I just start a new account on my existing MetaMask wallet?

Tags: solidity, metamask

Want to seperate the account that I use personally from the one I use for to learn and build on. Thanks

Good course so far :)
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should start a new account on the testnet in your existing MetaMask account, so you can keep track of the transactions, respective senders and recipients, and amount of ethers in your account. The course you have is very comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense, figured as much. And yes the course is very good. Another question, also, if you start a new account, can it be tracked to the original wallet on MetaMask?

Comment: Yes, it can be tracked.

Comment: good to know :)